# sending messages in instagram with seleniu

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have successfully logged in to Instagram.
I have opened direct and click on New Messages.
Now I want to send messages by their nickname.
I saw a nickname exists under subtags, as well as the button similar to radio-check.
However, I couldn't click to enable the Next and send the message.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Next button will be enabled once you have selected one or more user to send message to.
Doing it manually(as you described that part of the problem is already solved), you will see that if you Inspect the element, and use for instance Right click Copy XPATH, you can use the Next button with Selenium.

You didn't provide code example, but in my case it looks like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button")  # this is the XPATH of the Next button I copied
element.click()

# Your code here for the user selection

message_to_send="test"
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/textarea") # message box
element.send_keys(message_to_send)
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  # you can also hit Enter or search the new Send button
```

If you can elaborate more on your code, it would be easier to answer, but this should work.